# jQuery drag & drop works in html

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Does jQuery drag & drop functionality work on HTML as well? I used button tags and used same drag & drop jQuery function to get it work. But unfortunately it does not work? Is it possible to call drag & drop functions for HTML buttons? I would be glad if you can help me. Here is the code that I used for that.

```
alert("inside script");

$().ready(function() {
    alert("inside function");
    $("#submitme").draggable({revert: "invalid"});
    $("#button2").draggable({revert: "invalid"});
    $("#textarea1").droppable({
        accept: function(d)  {
            alert("droppable");
            if((d.attr("id")=="button2")){
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    alert("after script");
});
```

Comment: I think the more important question here is *why* are you trying to drag and drop form elements?

Comment: which part doesn't work exactly? None or just dropping?